# Code won't move down the available cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a booking system (plain drop down list feeding into VLOOKUP fields). I want to be able to copy the information across and I can do this easily. The problem is that I want the sheet to allow multiple bookings and every time one booking is done to allow a second one to be done. At the moment it just rewrites the previous booking, it won't move down the available cells!

Below is the code used, I know it could be neater but I am looking as to why it doesn't work. I have an error displaying on the With section 424 it comes up with and usually complains about UsedRange.

```
Sub Bookingtry()
'
' Bookingtry Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h
'
    Range("A2").Select
    Sheets("Booking Form").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking sheet").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("B2").Select
    Sheets("Booking Form").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking sheet").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("C2").Select
    Sheets("Booking Form").Select
    Range("B6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking sheet").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D2").Select
    Sheets("Booking Form").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking sheet").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E2").Select
    Sheets("Booking Form").Select
    Range("B10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking sheet").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Booking Form").Select
    Range("B12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking sheet").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("G2").Select
    Sheets("Booking Form").Select
    Range("B14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Booking sheet").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With Sheets("Booking sheet").Cells(UsedRange.Columns(1).Rows.Count + 1, 1).Paste
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: I have an error displaying on the With section 424 it comes up with and usually complains about UsedRange. I am not great with VBA must admit

Comment: I don't know if you can see the Close votes, but please take the habit to describe what you are trying/expecting to do, because here we must read between the (dirty) lines of code to hope understand what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I clean you code to see what you were trying to do, I guess that I'm ok for the first part.

But for your last "line" (the `With` with `UsedRange`), I don't really get what you are trying to paste... Everything else was already pasted. Anyway, I corrected the syntax of that last part too so that you can use it.

Give this a look :

```
Sub Bookingtry()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+h

Dim FirstEmptyRow As Long, _
    WsBF As Worksheet, _
    WsBS As Worksheet

Set WsBF = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Booking Form")
Set WsBS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Booking sheet")

FirstEmptyRow = WsBS.Range("A" & WsBS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    WsBF.Range("B2").Copy
    WsBS.Range("A" & FirstEmptyRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    WsBF.Range("B4").Copy
    WsBS.Range("B" & FirstEmptyRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    WsBF.Range("B6").Copy
    WsBS.Range("C" & FirstEmptyRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    WsBF.Range("B8").Copy
    WsBS.Range("D" & FirstEmptyRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    WsBF.Range("B10").Copy
    WsBS.Range("E" & FirstEmptyRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    WsBF.Range("B12").Copy
    WsBS.Range("F" & FirstEmptyRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    WsBF.Range("B14").Copy
    WsBS.Range("G" & FirstEmptyRow).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I get a runtime error 1004 on that one. I know the items are copied but I wanted to, after copying items across, to move the cells down. For instance I do the booking of one event from Booking Form into Booking Sheet and when i do another one the Booking is stored on the line beneath the previous one. The original code works with copying across it just doesnt move the line down to the next available row.

Comment: Ok, give the edit a try, that should work smoothly with the variable `FirstEmptyRow`! ;)

Comment: Works perfectly thank you very much now to read it all and take it all in